# How can I use an environment variable in a key inside of yaml file

Tags: environment-variables, docker-compose, yaml

I have the following .env file:

```
# ENV
ENVIRONMENT=local
SITENAME=reo
```

I have the following docker-compose.yml (part of it) file:

```
volumes:
  ${SITENAME}-sync:
     external: true
```

I get the following error:

```
 volumes value '${SITENAME}-sync' does not match any of the regexes: u'^[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+$'
```

Is it possible to have a variable as a key in a Yaml file?

I noticed that: `key: ${SITENAME}` does work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Environment variables are not possible for keys in docker-compose.yml, only for values. See [here](https://github.com/docker/compose/pull/3108#issuecomment-248038373)

Comment: Does this extend to node as well? I am trying to use a variable as a key for an object

Answer (score 0):

Since `docker-compose` doesn't support interpolation in keys, you'd need to add another level of indirection, e.g. use a templating tool like `mustache` or `handlebars`, and generate the `docker-compose.yml` file yourself from env vars.